# Function not looping in python

Tags: python, function, loops, selenium-webdriver

Would someone be able to tell me why my function (delete_loop) only runs once before exiting? I want it to run 200 times in a row before continuing the code again. ⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭  ⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭ ⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭

Thanks

```
def delete_loop(count):
    if count == 0:
        return
    # Click the dropdown
    dropdown_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.dropdown > .btn')
    try:
        dropdown_button.click()
    except ElementClickInterceptedException:
        pass
    except ElementNotInteractableException:
        pass

    # Click the delete
    delete_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.btn-delete')
    try:                
        delete_button.click()
    except ElementClickInterceptedException:
        pass
    except ElementNotInteractableException:
        pass

    # Click the ok
    ok_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button#alertify-ok')
    try:
        ok_button.click()
    except ElementClickInterceptedException:
        pass
    except ElementNotInteractableException:
        pass
    
    # Call the function again with decremented count
    delete_loop(count - 1)

# Continuous loop
while True:
    try:
        # Load the ASINs
        input_asins(driver)

        time.sleep(60)

        # Click the download
        download_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.zg-btn-white')
        try:
            download_button.click()
            time.sleep(5) # Wait for 5 seconds to allow the file to download
        except ElementClickInterceptedException:
            pass
        except ElementNotInteractableException:
            pass

        delete_loop(200)

    except Exception as e:
        time.sleep(10)
        input_asins(driver)

     
# Close the Selenium driver
driver.quit()
```

Full Code

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotInteractableException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


# Set up the Selenium driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-notifications') # Disable notifications
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# Wait for 2 minutes before starting
time.sleep(60)

driver.get("https://my.zonguru.com/#!/sales-spy")

def input_asins(driver):
    # Load the ASINs from the CSV file
    asins = []
    with open('asins.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            asins.extend(row)

    # Input the ASINs
    asins_to_input = asins[:200]
    asins = asins[200:]
    asin_input = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input.asins-counter__input')
    asin_input.clear()
    asin_input.send_keys(','.join(asins_to_input))

    # Remove the ASINs that have been inputted
    with open('asins.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows([asins])

    # Select the 'AU' option
    country_select = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="private-content"]/div/div/div/zg-product-tracker/div/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/div/select')
    try:
        country_select.click()
    except ElementClickInterceptedException:
        pass
    except ElementNotInteractableException:
        pass
    au_option = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'option[value="AU"]')
    try:
        au_option.click()
    except ElementClickInterceptedException:
        pass
    except ElementNotInteractableException:
        pass

    # Click the submit button
    submit_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.zg-btn-green')
    try:
        submit_button.click()
    except ElementClickInterceptedException:
        pass
    except ElementNotInteractableException:
        pass

def delete_loop(count):
    if count == 0:
        return
    # Click the dropdown
    dropdown_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.dropdown > .btn')
    try:
        dropdown_button.click()
    except ElementClickInterceptedException:
        pass
    except ElementNotInteractableException:
        pass

    # Click the delete
    delete_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.btn-delete')
    try:                
        delete_button.click()
    except ElementClickInterceptedException:
        pass
    except ElementNotInteractableException:
        pass

    # Click the ok
    ok_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button#alertify-ok')
    try:
        ok_button.click()
    except ElementClickInterceptedException:
        pass
    except ElementNotInteractableException:
        pass
    
    # Call the function again with decremented count
    delete_loop(count - 1)

# Continuous loop
while True:
    try:
        # Load the ASINs
        input_asins(driver)

        time.sleep(60)

        # Click the download
        download_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.zg-btn-white')
        try:
            download_button.click()
            time.sleep(5) # Wait for 5 seconds to allow the file to download
        except ElementClickInterceptedException:
            pass
        except ElementNotInteractableException:
            pass

        delete_loop(200)

    except Exception as e:
        time.sleep(10)
        input_asins(driver)

     
# Close the Selenium driver
driver.quit()
```

Comment: What is happening that makes you think the function only runs once?

Comment: This code is apart of a selenium webdriver that open a chrome tab, the function is meant to delete products from a website continuously, however this only run's once before running the 'input_asins'

Comment: In the bottom `except Exception as e` block, print the exception.  I suspect some other exception is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can start your function like this:

```
def delete_loop(count):
    for i in range(count):
        # Click the dropdown
        dropdown_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.dropdown > .btn')
```

Then you need to indent the following codes once to the right. Also, remove this call:
`delete_loop(count - 1)`

Answer (score -2):

shouldn't it be like this:

```
 delete_loop(count -= 1)
```

and instead of checking if, I would do a while loop